# Is it possible to pass a variable column name into an update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of data that lists values by 12 period columns. I'm trying to zero  the previous months data at the beginning of the month unsuccessfully. First part of my query returns the column name, I would then like to pass this into the Update statement but thats where everything goes wrong?? Please help.*

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT listofperiod FROM [periods] P 
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT monthofyear 
                          FROM  ref_calender RC 
                          WHERE RC.date = Dateadd(m,-1,CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())))
                          RC ON P.monthofyear = RC.monthofyear) 

UPDATE FD SET  @A = 0 
       FROM   [test_table] FD 
       INNER JOIN [glx]AG ON FD.company = AG.company 
       AND FD.acctnum = AG.account_id  '
```

Comment: No; you can't select the column to be updated via a variable/parameter to the query.  And one of the reasons why your schema is misdesigned is because the design makes it hard to query or update the data for a specific month.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use dynamic sql to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'UPDATE FD 
            SET ' + @A + '= 0 
            FROM   [test_table] FD 
           INNER JOIN [accpac_glx]AG 
                   ON FD.company = AG.company 
                      AND FD.acctnum = AG.account_id'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with multiple conditional `set` statements:

```
UPDATE FD 
SET    Period1 = (case when @A = 'Period1' then 0 else Period1 end),
       Period2 = (case when @A = 'Period2' then 0 else Period2 end),
       Period3 = (case when @A = 'Period3' then 0 else Period3 end),
       Period4 = (case when @A = 'Period4' then 0 else Period4 end)
FROM   [test_table] FD 
       INNER JOIN [glx]AG 
               ON FD.company = AG.company 
                  AND FD.acctnum = AG.account_id
```

That is, set the value to the current value, unless the flag (`@A`) says to reset the value to 0.